# How do I achieve a hibernate batch insert with Spring transactional (@Transactional)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using Spring 5.x and plain Hibernate in backend. I want to transfer data from one DataBase to another, 1000 records in one go as a batch. I have same tables in the both databases. We have configured 2 transaction mangers with 2 data source details.
I have configured batch-size="1000" in the hbm file as below.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class table="User" name="com.my.User" batch-size="1000">
  <id name="id" .../>
  <property name="name" ...>
  ...
```

I have the 2 service classes annotated with @Transactional and implemented as below.

```
@Transactional(value="oldDBTransactionManager" propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class GetUserServiceImpl extends HibernateDaoImpl implements GetUserService {
...
  public List<User> getAllUsers(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
            DetachedCriteria criteria =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
    
            List results = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria, firstResult, maxResults);
         
    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        for (User user: results ) {
            saveUserService.saveUser(user);
        }
    }
    return results;
...
}

 @Transactional(value="newDBTransactionManager" propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
    public class SaveUserServiceImpl extends HibernateDaoImpl implements SaveUserService{
    ...
        @Transactional(value="newDBTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    @Qualifier("newDBTransactionManager")
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
    }
    ...
```

I am calling the above getAllUsers service method from outside of the Service layer(outside Transaction) and it will internally calls saveUser service method (which usesanother transaction manger) as below:

```
public class UserProcessActivity{
    private int maxUsersPerIteration = 50;
    ...
    private void processUsers(){
        List<User> usersList;

        long counter = 0;
        int firstResult = 0;
        usersList = getUserService.getAllUsers(firstResult, maxUsersPerIteration);

        while (!usersList.isEmpty()) {
           // some logic...    
            firstResult += usersList .size();
            usersList = getUserService.getAllUsers(firstResult, maxUserPerIteration);
        }
    }
...
```

My question here is whether the above code handles batch insert or not?

If yes, what is the number of records insert as a batch 1000(batch-size declared in hbm)  or 50 (calling service method with maxUserPerIteration assigned with 50).

If it does not perform insert operation as batch, how to achieve the batch insert with Spring @Trasactional and Hibernate?

How to enable logging for this batch insert operation queries to understand actual batch operation information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest a read of [this blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) which explains what you need to configure in hibernate to achieve batch processing.